# How do I put a space in a help command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I am making a help command for my bot and I have this section called "Bot Stuff" but it requires me to put a _ or - in order for it to work.

````
async def help(ctx, category=None):
  if category == None:
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Sachs Bot", description="V 0.03", color=0x690303)
    embedVar.add_field(name="```Bot Stuff```", value="Does bot stuff", inline=False)
  if category == 'Bot Stuff':
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Bot Stuff", description="Bot Stuff", color=0x690303)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Discord.py** automatically splits string for command arguments.
So, `!help test category` will be split into `test` and `category`. To prevent it you can do this:

```py
async def help(ctx, *, category=None):
```

Then `!help test category` will be 1 argument `test category`.